# if value reach certain threshold the next one can't go under

Tags: r, markov-chains

Hi everyone im trying to obtain this:

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KZ8E.png)

I'm using R to simulate a Markov Chain and the State 4 is an absorbing state, I need that once the client has entered into the state 4 the client has to remain in that state the rest of the time.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Hi. try to give an actual example of your data instead of the picture of your data. It will save time for those who want to answer or help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Depending on what you want this might work: `ave(dat$value, dat$Id, FUN = function(x) ifelse(cumsum(x==4)>=1, 4, x))`. You can then assign it to a new variable. A little more clarification on the question would be helpful though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A twist on @erocoar's solution as I think it might not be what OP need:

```
dat$new_value <- unlist(tapply(dat$value, dat$Id, function(x) ifelse(cumsum(x==4) >0,4,x)))
```

modified example:

```
dat = data.frame(Id = rep(c("A", "B"), c(4, 3)),
                 value = c(1, 5, 4, 1, 1, 4, 1))

dat$new_value <- unlist(tapply(dat$value, dat$Id, function(x) ifelse(cumsum(x==4) >0,4,x)))

# dat
#   Id value new_value
# 1  A     1         1
# 2  A     5         5
# 3  A     4         4
# 4  A     1         4
# 5  B     1         1
# 6  B     4         4
# 7  B     1         4
```

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using `cummax` (thanks to @Moody_Mudskipper for pointing this out) E.g.,

```
dat = data.frame(Id = rep(c("A", "B"), c(4, 3)),
                 value = c(1, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 1))

dat$value <- unlist(tapply(dat$value, dat$Id, cummax))

  Id value
1  A     1
2  A     1
3  A     4
4  A     4
5  B     4
6  B     4
7  B     4
```

Comment: there's a `cummax` function you can use instead of `Reduce` and `max`

Comment: you're welcome :). however I'm not sure it's what OP wants, though for this case it works. I think values should change only if 4 was met before, so not a matter of max.